# int[] stored into an object in Java

Tags: java, object, collections, hashmap

I have a scenario where a value is declared as

```
 int[] rate = new int[] {5,6};
 int length = 26;
```

some processing is done and this is stored into a `HashMap<String,Object>` , so the `HashMap` contains

```
"rate" ==> {5,6}
"length" ==> 26
```

when I retrieve this for "key length" I am able to see the corresponding values but not for the "key rate" , is there a correct way for retrieving the values of rate too?

when I try `System.out.print` I cannot see legible values.

Comment: We will really need more code than this to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `rate` is an Array, you'll have to use `Arrays.toString(rate)` to see its string representation.

The illegible values you see is the default `toString()` implementation for arrays. It's usually the `Classname@hashCode`

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.print(parameter)` will always call the `toString()` upon the passed in parameter, in your case is an Array, the calling `toString()`printed result make no sense, you'd iterate the Array and print it one by one. something like this:

```
    int[] rate = (int[]) hashmap.get("rate");
    for (int i = 0, len = rate.length; i < len; i++) {
        System.out.println(rate[i]);
    }
```